# How many ways to multiply $n$ matrices?

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have 4 matrices A,B,C,D I can multiply them like this

`((AB)C)D = (A(BC))D = (AB)(CD) = A((BC)D) = A(B(CD))`

So, how many ways can n matrices be multiplied?

I thought it should be `C(n+1,n)` Because there are `n` matrices and we are putting the brackets in `n+1` boxes then I realised that multiple brackets can reside in the same box.

I found another answer `(1/n)C(2(n-1),n-1)` however I dont know how this works. Can somebody explain this solution if it is correct?

Comment: For consistency, your `((A(BC))D)` should be `(A(BC))D`.

Comment: Corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We see in OPs example all $5$ different ways to multiply four matrices according to the associative law. This corresponds to the *[Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)*

$$C_3=\frac{1}{4}\binom{6}{3}=5$$.

We write these $5$ variants explicitely with dots and obtain

\begin{align*}
  &(((A \cdot B)\cdot C)\cdot D)\\
  &((A\cdot (B\cdot C))\cdot D)\\
  &((A\cdot B)\cdot (C\cdot D))\\
  &(A\cdot ((B\cdot C)\cdot D))\\
  &(A\cdot (B\cdot (C\cdot D)))\\
  \end{align*}

> We can *bijectively transform* this represention into strings of valid pairs of open and closed parentheses. We do so by skipping the matrices and all open parentheses and replacing the dots with opening parentheses.
>
> \begin{align*}
>   &(\ )\ (\ )\ (\ )\\
>   &(\ (\ )\ )\ (\ )\\
>   &(\ )\ (\ (\ )\ )\\
>   &(\ (\ )\ (\ )\ )\\
>   &(\ (\ (\ )\ )\ )\\
>   \end{align*}
>
> In general we consider strings of length $2n$ consisting of $n$ open and $n$ closed parentheses. Valid sequences can be characterized, that parsing a string from left to right, starting with $0$ from the beginning and *adding* $1$ when reading an open parenthesis and *subtracting* $1$ when reading a closed parenthesis we always get a non-negative number. At the end we get $0$.
>
> Now let's count the number $C_n$ of all valid sequences of length $2n$. The number of *all* sequences is
>   \begin{align*}
>   \binom{2n}{n}
>   \end{align*}
>
> A *bad* sequence contains $n$ open and $n$ closed parentheses, but reaches the value $-1$ at a certain step for the first time during parsing. When we have reached the value $-1$ we have parsed precisely one closing parentheses more than open parentheses.
>
> We now *reverse* from that point on all parentheses, i.e. we exchange all open with closed parentheses and vice-versa. This results in a sequence  with  two more closed parentheses than open parentheses. So we have a total of $n+1$ closed parentheses and $n-1$ open parentheses.
>
> It follows, the number of *bad* sequences is
>   \begin{align*}
>   \binom{2n}{n+1}
>   \end{align*}

$$ $$

> We conclude the number $C_n$ of all valid sequences of length $2n$ is
>   \begin{align*}
>   C_n=\binom{2n}{n}-\binom{2n}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\qquad \qquad n\geq 1
>   \end{align*}

In OPs example $n\geq 2$ matrices imply $n-1$ dots for multiplication. These dots can be substituted with $n-1$ open parentheses giving $C_{n-1}=\frac{1}{n}\binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}$ different valid arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

If number of matrices are let us assume $M$.
 Then number of ways to Multiply $M$ Matrices are = 
$$[(2N)!/(N+1)!N! ]$$
                                           Where $N=M-1$

For example if I have $3$ matrices $A,B,C$
 We can multiply these $3$ by $2$ ways $(AB)C$ and $A(BC)$

Here $M$ $=$ $3$
          Take $N$ $=$ $M$$-$$1$
              $N$ $=$ $2$
        Then the number of ways to multiply these $3$ are $=$ $[(2*2)!/(2+1)!*2!]$

$Ans = 2$

Comment: could you explain a little bit how you got the expression ?