# Commutative extension to Catalan's problem

Tags: combinatorics

Another question asks for the [number of ways to multiply n matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630457/how-many-ways-to-multiply-n-matrices).

Matrices, however, are a rather special case, because although we are allowed to place parentheses in an arbitrary fashion without affecting the result, we are not allowed to change the order of the matrices, in the general case. For example, $A \cdot C \cdot B \cdot D \neq A \cdot C \cdot B \cdot D$.

In this question we presume that the factors are commutative. So, if we extend the exhaustive multiplication for four matrices from the accepted answer to the above question, additional combinations become possible, e.g.:

\begin{align*}
  &(((A \cdot B)\cdot C)\cdot D)\\
  &((A\cdot (B\cdot C))\cdot D)\\
  &((A\cdot B)\cdot (C\cdot D))\\
  &(A\cdot ((B\cdot C)\cdot D))\\
  &(A\cdot (B\cdot (C\cdot D)))\\
  &((A\cdot D)\cdot (C\cdot B))\\
  &((B\cdot D)\cdot (C\cdot A))\\
  &etc.\\
  \end{align*}

What would be the number of such combinations? Is there a way to exhaustively enumerate them?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simply $n!$ times the Catalan number. You can first permute the elements to any order and then do the paranthesisation. Every structure so achieved is different because placing paranthesis doesn't affect the order of the elements.

**EDIT:**

Further, if we do the calculation, we get the formula ($C_{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)$th Catalan number):

$$n!C_{n-1} = n! \frac{1}{n} { {2(n-1)}\choose{n-1} } = \frac{(2(n-1))!}{(n-1)!} = (2(n-1))P(n-1)$$

which seems to indicate you can make the choosing of the "permuted paranthesitysation" via choosing a permutation of length $n-1$ out of $2(n-1)$ objects, but I don't know "where this comes from" and how it can be seen combinatorially (my previous thinking was faulty).

Comment: That's a beautiful result